# Sliding puzzle (web game) - transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I'm making a sliding puzzle (something like [this](http://mypuzzle.org/sliding)) using HTML, CSS and JavaScript/jQuery.

Everything works fine, but I want to add a sliding transition each time a slide moves.

The code works based on the following logic:

- 12, 16 or 48 `<div>`s are created (depending on the level of difficulty).
- A `background-image` is  assigned to all of them, and cropped accordingly to simulate a "piece" of the original image.
- They all have a class of `image`, and also `piece<number>`, where `<number>` is the number of the tile. The last tile (`piece12`, `piece16` or `piece48`) also has a class of `voidBlock`, that removes the `background-image`. This is the empty tile that permits the ones directly next to it to move into its  place. All the other tiles have an additional class, `imgBlock`.
- When one of the tiles that are next to the `voidBlock` is clicked, it exchanges classes with the `voidBlock`. For example, if we were to click `piece6`, which happens to be next to the `voidBlock`(let's say the difficulty is set to easy, and thus `voidBlock` is `piece12`), this would happen:

  1. The original `voidBlock` changes its `piece12` class to `piece6`.
  2. The original `voidBlock` changes its `voidBlock` class to `imgBlock`.
  3. The original `piece6` changes its `piece6` class to `piece12`.
  4. The original `piece6` changes its `imgBlock` class to `voidBlock`.

  After that, a `draw()` function is called; it sets the `background-position` of each tile, depending on its `piece` number.

As you might have guessed by now, none of the `<div>`s actually move. They remain still as the `background-position` of their `background-image` changes through their classes.

Although I do have some experience in programming (namely in Python and Java), web development in general is very new to me. I have tried various methods of transitioning, but the best thing I could come up with was to have the background image move each time a tile moved (which is just weird and unintuitive).

My question is, thus: is there any way to have an animation/transition of the tiles sliding each time that they move?

---

## **Code**

*(the lines that are commented out have nothing to do with the question)*

**CSS:**

Part of the `main.css` file:

```
.image {
   background-image: url(/Users/user/puzzle-test/img/image001.jpg);
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: top;
   margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.voidBlock {
    background-image: none;
}

.imgBlock {
    background-image: url(/Users/user/puzzle-test/img/image001.jpg);
}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery:**

The `<div>` click handler:

```
var clickHandler = function() {
    var voidPosX = $(".voidBlock").css("left");
    var voidPosY = $(".voidBlock").css("top");
    voidPosX = parseInt(voidPosX.substring(0, voidPosX.length-2));
    voidPosY = parseInt(voidPosY.substring(0, voidPosY.length-2));

    var posX = $(this).css("left");
    var posY = $(this).css("top");
    posX = parseInt(posX.substring(0, posX.length-2));
    posY = parseInt(posY.substring(0, posY.length-2));

    if((voidPosX == posX - finalWidth) && (voidPosY == posY)){
        posX -= finalWidth;
        voidPosX += finalWidth;
        move($(this));
    }else if((voidPosX == posX + finalWidth) && (voidPosY == posY)){
        posX += finalWidth;
        voidPosX -= finalWidth;
        move($(this));
    }else if((voidPosY == posY - finalHeight) && (voidPosX == posX)){
        posY -= finalHeight;
        voidPosY += finalHeight;
        move($(this));
    }else if((voidPosY == posY + finalHeight) && (voidPosX == posX)){
        posY += finalHeight;
        voidPosY -= finalHeight;
        move($(this));
    }
}
```

The `move` function (used in the click handler) (`h` and `v` are the horizontal and vertical dimensions of the puzzle):

```
function move(element) {
    //moveCounter++;

    var temp = element.attr("class").split(" ");
    for(var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
        if(temp[i].substring(0, 5) == "piece"){
            var pieceNum = temp[i].substring(5);
        }
    }

    element.addClass("tempBlock1");
    $(".voidBlock").addClass("tempBlock2");

    element.filter(".tempBlock1").addClass("piece"+(h*v));
    element.filter(".tempBlock1").removeClass("piece"+pieceNum);
    element.filter(".tempBlock1").addClass("voidBlock");
    element.filter(".tempBlock1").removeClass("imgBlock");


    $(".voidBlock").filter(".tempBlock2").addClass("piece"+pieceNum);
    $(".voidBlock").filter(".tempBlock2").removeClass("piece"+(h*v));
    $(".voidBlock").filter(".tempBlock2").addClass("imgBlock");
    $(".voidBlock").filter(".tempBlock2").removeClass("voidBlock");

    $(".tempBlock1").removeClass("tempBlock1");
    $(".tempBlock2").removeClass("tempBlock2");

    draw();
}
```

The `draw` function (the numbers 800 and 600 represent the dimensions of the image):

```
function draw() {
    //var imgSelect = $("input[type='radio'][name='bgImage']:checked").val();

    var j = 1;
    for(var pY = 0; pY > -600; pY -= finalHeight){
        for(var pX = 0; pX > -800; pX -= finalWidth){
            $(".piece"+j).css("background-position", pX+"px "+pY+"px");

            //$(".piece"+j).css("background-image", "url(/Users/user/puzzle-test/img/"+imgSelect+".jpg)");
            //$(".piece"+j).find(".helpNum").text(j);

            j++;
        }
    }

    //$(".move").text("Moves: " + moveCounter);

    $(".voidBlock").css("background-image", "none");

    //$(".grid").find("img").attr("src", "img/"+imgSelect+".jpg");
    //$(".image:not(.voidBlock)").css("cursor", "pointer");
    //$(".voidBlock").css("cursor", "default");
}
```

Finally, the `<div>`s are created by the `shuffle` function, like this (`pieces` is a shuffled array of the puzzle pieces, basically used to tell where to position each tile):

```
// DRAW
for(var i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++){

    // HTML
    var el = "<div class=\"image piece"+(pieces[i])+"\"><p class=\"helpNum\"></p></div>";
    $(".grid").append(el);

    $(".piece"+(h*v)).addClass("voidBlock");
}

// CSS div positioning
var j = 0;
for(var pY = 0; pY > -600; pY -= finalHeight){
    for(var pX = 0; pX > -800; pX -= finalWidth){
        $(".piece"+pieces[j]).css({left: pX, top: pY});
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: JQuery's animate would potentially allow you to move the items when they swap: http://api.jquery.com/animate/ It may be as simple as swapping out the relevant `.css()` for `.animate()`

Comment: When you've solved this, please take a look at chaining in jQuery, you're doing an awful lot of unnecessary DOM queries ;)

Comment: Why the approach of swapping the classes and changing the background image? Why not keep the class the same and just chance the position of the element using `.css()` or `.animate()`?

Comment: @DBS thank you for your answer. I've tried doing that, and unfortunately it doesn't work (sometimes it even breaks my code). The only thing that works is adding a `transition` property to the `.css` file, but that just ends up being the weird background-sliding effect I'm describing in my question.

Comment: @BillyNate thank you for your suggestion, I do have to learn to code better in jQuery, though it's been just 5 days since I first started :)

To answer your other question, I tried changing the `top` and `left` properties of the `<div>`s, but that required setting their position to `absolute` and it quickly became a mess I could not handle. If that is the only way to make it work, though, I have to give it another shot.

Comment: I can see why `position: absolute` will give you a mess a first, but I'd recommend you to retry it. The other way would be by using the `left` and `top` in the `.animate()`, and in the callback swap the order of the elements and reset the `left` and `top`, but personally I would consider the latter approach harder.

Comment: If you want an answer to this question actually solving your problem, you really should add a working [code snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Also we could discuss every detail in a chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it thanks to @BillyNate 's answer, which was to set the `position` property of the `<div>`s to absolute, then move them by changing the `top` and `left` properties.